# IntelliJ IDEA 9 CE "Create New Class" dialog UI element purpose

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 9 Community Edition for Java project. On "Create New Class" dialog you can see some strange UI element (highlighted in red). 
[image]

What is the purpose of this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an indicator to tell the user that he can use the keyboard arrows to change the kind of class.

---

**Resources :**

- [IntelliJ's YouTrack - In the "Create New Class" dialog box, an Up and Down arrow appears after the Name: field. They don't appear to do anything.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-54179)

Comment: At least it works and now it seems obvious. But I expected something more interesting...